# Pandas Dataframe header do not match correct column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I print pandas dataframe with this code

```
df=pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(output),skiprows=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9])

new_header = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.columns = new_header

print(df)
```

It show output like this. The dataframe header do not match correct column. ID header not on the column 2.

```
0             ID    MAC            Name              Group   IP             Type            State  STA Uptime          ExtraInfo
1    0     10c0-ffff-0000 TEST-A1 @1ABCD -              AP12345        idle   0   -               -                 
2    1     10c0-ffff-000f TEST-A2 @2ABCD 10.20.0.1      AP12345        nor    1   12D:5H:10M:16S  -
```

I use `print(df.columns)` it show output like this. It look like header not separate.

```
Index(['ID    MAC            Name              Group   IP             Type            State  STA Uptime          ExtraInfo'], dtype='object', name=0)
```

I export to csv it show data in same line like this picture.
[image]

So I edit code by using delim_whitespace like this.

```
df=pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(output),skiprows=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9],delim_whitespace=True)
```

The output of `print(df.columns)` show header like this.

```
Index(['STA', 'Uptime', 'ExtraInfo'], dtype='object', name=('ID', 'MAC', 'Name', 'Group', 'IP', 'Type', 'State'))
```

I export data to csv but it show header 3 column only like this picture.

[image]

I `print(df)` it show output like this.

```
('ID', 'MAC', 'Name', 'Group', 'IP', 'Type', 'State')
STA  ... ExtraInfo
0
10c0-ffff-0000 TEST-A1        @1ABCD -              AP12345 idle  0    ...  -       
1
10c0-ffff-000f TEST-A2        @1ABCD 10.20.0.1      AP12345 nor   0    ...  -
```

Why dataframe header do not match correct column? How to fix it?

Comment: What does your file look like? Some comparison of input and output data will be helpful.

Comment: I think you should probably consider using separator while reading the CSV file.

Comment: Now I read data from telnet not csv file. I will save to csv before read to dataframe. Thank you.

Comment: I just edit question by add picture export data from telnet to csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with 1 line unless I'm understanding incorrectly:

`df=pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(output),skiprows=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9], header=None,names=['ID', 'MAC', 'Name', 'Group', 'IP', 'Type', 'State'])`

Answer (score 0):

From the data you described, you can just combine two approaches, you just have to turn the header off, and then do, as you did in the first attempt. I hope this will work out for you!

```
df=pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(output), header=None, skiprows=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9], delim_whitespace=True)

new_header = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.columns = new_header

print(df.columns)
```